# почему не присваивается значение?

Tags: java, коллекции

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/* Задача по алгоритмам
Написать программу, которая:
1. вводит с консоли число N > 0
2. потом вводит N чисел с консоли
3. выводит на экран максимальное из введенных N чисел.
*/

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String raz = reader.readLine();
    int razi = Integer.parseInt(raz);

    List myList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i<razi;i++){
        String x = reader.readLine();
        int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
        myList.add(y);

    }
    int maxi =  Collections.max(myList);


    System.out.println(Collections.max(myList));

    }
}
```

Если убрать строку `int maxi =  Collections.max(myList);` то код выполняется без проблем. Но меня заинтересовало, почему я не могу присвоить максимальное значение из списка переменной `maxi` ? IDE показывает ошибку.

Comment: А какую ошибку?

Comment: Error:(30, 36) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке объясняет вам, в чём дело.

Поскольку вы пользуетесь нетипизированным `List`, то заявленный тип объектов в нём — `Object`. Поэтому заявленный тип максимума — тоже `Object`. И то, что там на самом деле будет число, неважно. Вы могли бы положить в него и строку, и любой другой объект, как компилятору проконтролировать?

Вы должны задекларировать, что в вашем списке будут лишь числа:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Тогда при попытке вставить туда не число компилятор на вас наругается.

Comment: Можно и так, да )

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `Collections.max(myList)` возвращает объект и вы его сразу пытаетесь присвоить `int`. Делайте так:

```
int maxi = (Integer) Collections.max(myList);
```

Comment: а разве возвращаемый объект не является числом? ведь функция то математическая, и если бы в list были бы одни string-и , то жтот метод не сработал бы ( выдал бы ошибку ) .

Comment: @ArazHajiyev, почему же? Это бы и со строками сработало.

Comment: и какой был бы результат? )))) максимальное что оно выдало бы? ))

Comment: @ArazHajiyev, вернуло бы максимальный элемент в лексикографическом порядке. Например, если бы ввели "a,b,c", то выдало бы "c".

Comment: понятно . Спасибо большое !

Comment: @ArazHajiyev: `Collections.max` пытается сравнить между собой элементы. Если оно может сравнить (например, все они числа или строки), возвращается максимум. Если не может (например, есть и числа, и строки), произойдёт ошибка времени выполнения. Вот пример: http://ideone.com/MycFsz